# Flying saucer detect page break?

Tags: java, flying-saucer

I have a `productGroups` List, inside each product group I have a list of `product`. I want to loop every item in `productGroups` and all `product` inside each `productGroup`.

So I have created a table to display all product inside each product group and I put product group name on top of each table so user can know product belong which product group.

The problem is. if product list to long and break to a new page. I want to put product group name(`<p class="product-group">[[${productGroup.getPgNumber()}]] - [[${productGroup.getPgName()}]]</p>`) in that new page.

How can I do it?

```html
    <div th:each="productGroup: ${productGroups}">
            <p class="product-group">[[${productGroup.getPgNumber()}]] - [[${productGroup.getPgName()}]]</p>
            <table >
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>BRAND</th>
                    <th>MODEL</th>
                    <th>FEATURE TEXT</th>
                    <th>M.P.</th>
                    <th>ARTICLE</th>
                    <th>PRO</th>
                    <th>SAL</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="audit: ${productGroup.getAudits()}">
                    <td width="10%" th:text="${audit.getBranch()}"></td>
                    <td width="10%" th:text="${audit.getModel()}"></td>
                    <td width="40%" th:text="${audit.getFeatureText()}"></td>
                    <td width="10%" th:text="${audit.getMultiPack()}"></td>
                    <td width="10%" th:text="${audit.getArticleNumber()}"></td>
                    <td width="10%" th:text="${audit.getPro()}"></td>
                    <td width="10%" th:text="${audit.getSal()}"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS to indicate you don't want page break into you div:

```
    div{page-break-inside:avoid}
```